# Adding views to LinearLayout programmatically not setting text on all but one

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have a linear layout and want to dynamically add a variable number of list items. (It can't be a recycler view because this list is already in a recycler view and is assumed to be a small list.)  But for some reason, it does not save the text I set except for the last item. If I added another item with a different title, then the last one added will be shown, and the others will say "default". Does anyone know what is going on? It's really strange. Thanks!

Here is the code:

settings_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        style="?android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:text="Default"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

root_settings_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp">
</LinearLayout>
```

SettingsView.java:

```
public class SettingsView extends LinearLayout {

    //Views
    private View view;

    /**
     * Constructor for android tools to use.
     */
    public SettingsView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param parent
     */
    public SettingsView(ViewGroup parent) {
        super(parent.getContext());

        //Get the inflated layout
        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.root_settings_view, parent, false);


        View itemView = LinearLayout.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.settings_item, view);
        ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Hi");
        ((CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(true);


        View itemView2 = LinearLayout.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.settings_item, view);
        ((TextView) itemView2.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Hello");
        ((CheckBox) itemView2.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(false);

        View itemView3 = LinearLayout.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.settings_item, view);
        ((TextView) itemView3.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Bye");
        ((CheckBox) itemView3.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(true);

        View itemView4 = LinearLayout.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.settings_item, view);
        ((TextView) itemView4.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Test");
        ((CheckBox) itemView4.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(false);

        addView(view);
    }
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You cant have the same id when you are inflating it for each of the item, what you want is instead of inflating it you need to `addView` the list item to the parent `view`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @Rod_Algonquin for your comment, which convinced me that I have to make a widget for this. Luckily I had done widgets before, so I knew how to do it. I just was trying to avoid it, but I guess it has problems with the duplicate IDs if we do not use widgets.

The following code made it work:

Added new class, SettingItemView.java:

```
/**
 * A item view with the title and a checkbox.
 */
public class SettingItemView extends LinearLayout {

    private TextView mTitle;
    private CheckBox mCheckBox;

    public SettingItemView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.settings_item, this);
        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        mTitle.setText(title);
    }

    public void setCheckbox(boolean checked) {
        mCheckBox.setChecked(checked);
    }
}
```

Changed this constructor method:

```
/**
 *
 * @param parent
 */
public SettingsView(ViewGroup parent) {
        super(parent.getContext());

        //Get the inflated layout.
        LinearLayout view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.root_settings_view, parent, false);


        SettingItemView itemView = new SettingItemView(parent.getContext());
        itemView.setTitle("Hi");
        itemView.setCheckbox(true);
        view.addView(itemView);

        SettingItemView itemView2 = new SettingItemView(parent.getContext());
        itemView2.setTitle("Hello");
        itemView2.setCheckbox(true);
        view.addView(itemView2);

        SettingItemView itemView3 = new SettingItemView(parent.getContext());
        itemView3.setTitle("Bye");
        itemView3.setCheckbox(true);
        view.addView(itemView3);

        addView(view);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are basically running over it and adding only the last one , this code should work:

public SettingsView(ViewGroup parent) {
        super(parent.getContext());

```
    //Get the inflated layout
    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.root_settings_view, parent, false);


    View itemView = LinearLayout.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.settings_item, view);
    ((TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Hi");
    ((CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(true);
    addView(view);
    View itemView2 = LinearLayout.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.settings_item, view);
    ((TextView) itemView2.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Hello");
    ((CheckBox) itemView2.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(false);
    addView(view);
    View itemView3 = LinearLayout.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.settings_item, view);
    ((TextView) itemView3.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Bye");
    ((CheckBox) itemView3.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(true);
    addView(view);
    View itemView4 = LinearLayout.inflate(parent.getContext(), R.layout.settings_item, view);
    ((TextView) itemView4.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Test");
    ((CheckBox) itemView4.findViewById(R.id.checkbox)).setChecked(false);

    addView(view);
```

Comment: This gave me infinite recursion in LogCat showing this line over and over: ` at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6713)`

Comment: I thought the same thing, except for `addView(itemView)` etc. However, that does not explain why anything is shown at all - as I see it, only `root_settings_view` is added to the `ViewGroup`.

Comment: I think yanivtwin misunderstood my code, because I'm actually adding the root view (where I inflated 4 item views) to the parent LinearLayout, not adding any items. They were only added by the inflation method. When I tried adding items manually, it gave me a recursion problem.